# Access cookie value with Twig template

Tags: php, twig

After user submit login form and if checkbox "Remember me" is clicked, username will be stored in cookie variable. After that when user tries to login again, his username should appear in username field of login form. But I cant get the cookie value with Twig template. Cookie exists in $_COOKIE superglobal variable, but I dont know how to access it via twig template.

Tried to access it with this piece of code below but it doesnt work.

```
{% if app.request.cookies.has('remember_me') %}
  {{app.request.cookies.get('remember_me')}}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22959285/11249686) will solve your problem.

> You can use Twigs `addGlobal` function to do so. [See
>   manual](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#globals)
>
> ```
> // Add static text
> $twig->addGlobal('text', 'Hello World');
> // Add array
> $twig->addGlobal('arr', array(1, 2, 3));
> // Add objects
> $twig->addGlobal('obj', $obj);
> ```

You can just add a Global named `cookies` and set it to `$_COOKIE`. You now can access cookies by calling the cookies variable from inside twig.